# Как распарсить википедию, используя Python 3? Какие библиотеки нужны?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, поиск-библиотек, wikipedia

Как распарсить сайт используя Python 3? Какие библиотеки для этого нужны?

Нужна страница обычная википeдии, чтобы из нее можно было взять определение.

Пример страницы:
[Algorithm](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC)

Вот определение:

> Алгори́тм (лат. al­go­rithmi — от арабского имени математика Аль-Хорезми[1]) — конечная совокупность точно заданных правил решения произвольного класса задач или набор инструкций, описывающих порядок действий исполнителя для решения некоторой задачи. В старой трактовке вместо слова «порядок» использовалось слово «последовательность», но по мере развития параллельности в работе компьютеров слово «последовательность» стали заменять более общим словом «порядок». Независимые инструкции могут выполняться в произвольном порядке, параллельно, если это позволяют используемые исполнители.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110394/discussion-between-andreymal-and-victor-vosmottor-thanks-monica).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`pip3 install wikipedia`](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/)

Example:

```
>>> import wikipedia
>>> print wikipedia.summary("Wikipedia")
# Wikipedia (/ˌwɪkɨˈpiːdiə/ or /ˌwɪkiˈpiːdiə/ WIK-i-PEE-dee-ə) is a collaboratively edited, multilingual, free Internet encyclopedia supported by the non-profit Wikimedia Foundation...

>>> wikipedia.search("Barack")
# [u'Barak (given name)', u'Barack Obama', u'Barack (brandy)', u'Presidency of Barack Obama', u'Family of Barack Obama', u'First inauguration of Barack Obama', u'Barack Obama presidential campaign, 2008', u'Barack Obama, Sr.', u'Barack Obama citizenship conspiracy theories', u'Presidential transition of Barack Obama']

>>> ny = wikipedia.page("New York")
>>> ny.title
# u'New York'
>>> ny.url
# u'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York'
>>> ny.content
# u'New York is a state in the Northeastern region of the United States. New York is the 27th-most exten'...
>>> ny.links[0]
# u'1790 United States Census'

>>> wikipedia.set_lang("fr")
>>> wikipedia.summary("Facebook", sentences=1)
# Facebook est un service de réseautage social en ligne sur Internet permettant d'y publier des informations (photographies, liens, textes, etc.) en contrôlant leur visibilité par différentes catégories de personnes.
```

---

[`pip install Wikipedia-API`](https://pypi.org/project/Wikipedia-API/)

Example:

```
def print_categorymembers(categorymembers, level=0, max_level=1):
        for c in categorymembers.values():
            print("%s: %s (ns: %d)" % ("*" * (level + 1), c.title, c.ns))
            if c.ns == wikipediaapi.Namespace.CATEGORY and level < max_level:
                print_categorymembers(c.categorymembers, level=level + 1, max_level=max_level)


cat = wiki_wiki.page("Category:Physics")
print("Category members: Category:Physics")
print_categorymembers(cat.categorymembers)

# Category members: Category:Physics
# * Statistical mechanics (ns: 0)
# * Category:Physical quantities (ns: 14)
# ** Refractive index (ns: 0)
# ** Vapor quality (ns: 0)
# ** Electric susceptibility (ns: 0)
# ** Specific weight (ns: 0)
# ** Category:Viscosity (ns: 14)
# *** Brookfield Engineering (ns: 0)
```

---

`pip3 install bs4`

`pip3 install requests`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup


url = 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python'


source = requests.get(url)
main_text = source.text
soup = Soup(main_text)

data = soup.find('div', {'class': 'mw-parser-output'})
print(data.p)
```

Answer (score 3):

Библиотеки: [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/), [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). 
Как парсить довольно подробно и на русском написано [здесь](http://wiki.python.su/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/BeautifulSoup)

Answer (score 2):

Достаточный для вашей цели модуль [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

В вашей программе затем сделайте импорт:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

чтобы использовать его и можете работать.